# Two apps in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I am building an app with express js which will have different clients like web and mobile. I didnt want to use one app for both as some middleware would be additional burden. For say like session middleware.  So is it possible for one project to have two apps. And how would it work?

Comment: Well, they'd either have to listen on two separate ports, or be deployed separately? Take a look at route specific middleware.

Comment: Why would the session middleware be a burden for mobile devices when the middleware runs on the server side?

Comment: @robertklep It would be because every request that comes from mobile also will have to pass through this middleware where as it doesn't need to, rather instead of that I could use Oauth middleware in that place.

Comment: @alexjamesbrown Yeah....I was thinking of making listen to a different port behind a proxy server like Nginx

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra do you have an actual issue with the mobile-session-middleware combo that requires you to rewrite stuff? I'm quite interested in hearing how the (pretty simple) session middleware can prove to be an issue for mobile clients.

Comment: I dont think it will create a problem. Just that I think its a bit of overhead for the mobile api part. Don't you agree? I would like to know why you think so?

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra the only thing that the session middleware exposes towards the client is setting a cookie. That's not a bottleneck. The method with which you implement sessions on the server side could cause requests to take a wee bit longer, but that would probably be negligible (esp. compared to mobile network latencies). In terms of impact on the mobile device (memory perhaps), I don't see any reason to go through the hassle of running two apps. And if you still want to leave out *just* the session middleware, I would use some sort of conditional middleware, but still just one app.

Comment: Whats a conditional middleware? Can the default session middleware given by express be made a conditional middleware?

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra here's a (possible) example on how to switch off the session middleware for mobile requests: [gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/02c2fb8cfb599b23006c)

Comment: Thanks for the gist!!!! But I wanted to ask something. How can I make that some middleware work say url /mysite/web and some other middleware work on url /mysite/mobile.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `app` object that you make in express is a function(req,res,next) that is suitable for Express's own middleware chains. So you can use `app.use` to send requests matching a leading path fragment to an app defined elsewhere.

Docs: http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.use

```
$ npm install express

//mobile.js
var app = require('express')();
app.get('/', function(req, res){ 
  res.send('Mobile Route') 
});
module.exports = app;


//desktopApp.js
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var desktopApp = express();
var mobileApp = require('./mobile.js');

desktopApp.use('/mobile', mobileApp)
desktopApp.use(desktopApp.router);
desktopApp.use(express.errorHandler());

desktopApp.get('/', function(req, res){ 
  res.send('Desktop Route') 
});

desktopApp.get('/mobile', function(req, res){ 
  // Because Express respects the order that you set up the middleware chain,
  // the mobileApp `/mobile` route gets first dibs to send a response or next()
  res.send('Inaccessible Desktop Route') 
});

desktopApp.get('/mobile/foobar', function(req, res){ 
  // When mobileApp can't find any suitable route matching this path, it gives
  // up, and desktopApp continues to pass the request down the middleware stack.
  // It ends up matching this route, where we send a response
  res.send('Desktop Route') 
});

http.createServer(desktopApp).listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('Listening on 3000');
});


// Results
$ curl localhost:3000/
Desktop Route

$ curl localhost:3000/mobile/
Mobile Route
```

Comment: I have never used @Iaconbase's vhost function, I can't speak to relative advantages of these approaches

Comment: Your approach seems to be very good. I am just guessing this but if I were to use some common middleware than I would put it above the mobile_app middleware right??

Comment: @Plato The [vhost function](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/vhost.html) is built-in on [connect](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/). Anyway, if both apps are similar it's better an approach like yours, my propose assumes that the apps are fully independent.

Comment: Yes, middleware above `app.use('/mobile', mobileApp)` will run for both. Express passes the requests along the middleware chain, until something sends a response. (Or your code neither sends a response nor call `next()`, in which case it just hangs.)

Comment: I added another route `/mobile/foobar` in the outer application, showing how Express passes the request into mobileApp, then back out into the rest of the desktopApp middleware stack. (Because mobileApp doesn't deign to respond to this request. `/mobile` never makes it back out of mobileApp as a response is sent.)

Comment: I really like your approach, so I am giving it the correct answer.

Comment: This is nearly the same as i proposed, it simply injects the mobile app as middleware into the desktop app. Anyway I recommend you deploying the mobile app through a subdomain rather than a path. `desktopApp.use( express.vhost(  'mobile', mobileApp ) )`

Comment: FWIW I think subdomains look a little cleaner than the leading `/mobile`, and I also prefer one app with a responsive layout over two apps. But it's great to have both my `use('/mountpoint', function)` and your `use(express.vhost())` method as answers here on the same page :D

Comment: @Plato Sure, both are valid approaches. I don't like this approach because I expect the desktop app to be totally independent from the mobile app and vice-versa, so that any of them does not refer in any way to the other. That's the reason because I prefer the extra app as the main entry point, rather than injecting one app into another.

Comment: Oh, gotcha. that's good practice; if I implemented my example I would probably have a third `app.js` that mounted `mobileApp` at `/mobile` and `desktopApp` at `/`

Answer (score 3):

### See [the vhost example on the express github repository](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/examples/vhost).

You can have a "main" app, which routes the requests to one app or another. You should write a middleware to establish the conditions where one app or another are requested. `express.vhost` is a good example, but maybe you need other checks than the domain one.

### main-app.js

(*The file called to start the server.*)

```js
// load dependencies

var main = express();

main.use( express.vhost( 'mobile', require( './the-mobile-app' ) );
main.use( express.vhost( '*', require( './the-web-app' ) );

main.listen( /*...*/ )
```

### `the-mobile-app` and `the-web-app.js`

```js
var app = express();
//
// setup your application conf, middleware, and routes
//
module.exports = app;
```

Comment: Its a good option to use....but I want to know will doing this not slow down each request. And what If I wanted to host the app behind a proxy-server like Nginx?

Comment: The performance impact is the lowest posible, even if you host the app behind a proxy. It's an app with 2 functions on the middleware chain so it's really fast. In addition, with this approach you have two fully independent apps than can be deployed independently, so it's easy to scale up the backend resources if needed.

Comment: Ok. So you believe this would be better than using  conditional middleware as mentioned by robertklep.

Comment: The approach is similar. robertklep and Plato propose conditional middleware with one app, while I propose 1 master app with the conditional middleware + 2 child apps for mobile and web sites. If there is a lot of code shared between mobile and web apps, my propose makes no sense. If they are really independent apps, this way is better for maintainability purposes.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I got your point. But yours seems to be a better option if I plan to deploy the mobile's server app in a sub-domain which I think would be a good thing to do. Whats your opinion?

Comment: I currently prefer making a responsive layout to avoid a mobile-specific version, but if a mobile version must be done I would deploy it in a sub-domain definitely. I prefer it rather than mounting the mobile version on a path. If you deploy it in a subdomain the connect's vhost function, accesible within `express.vhost`, perfectly fits your needs.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to share a different approach that I used in a project recently:

```
function renderAppropriate(template1, template2){
  return function(req, res){
    if(req.session && req.session.mobileOn){
      res.render(template1);
    } else {
      res.render(template2);
    }
  };
};

app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
  // do some stuff
  next()
}, renderAppropriate('someMobileTemplate', 'someDesktopTemplate')
);
```

Comment: I dont know why you have posted this answer, coz its not that i want to serve different templates to mobile browsers. Its an api for an mobile client of the app. I hope now you are able to understand why your answer doesn't valid here.

Comment: Yes that's fine I posted this because it is solves a similar problem in a different way, and it might be useful to others who find this page :)