# A node.js server as a hub for other web server projects

Tags: node.js

I want to have a personal website that I can put my web stuff on. Say the domain name being `something.com`. Now, I can run multiple instances of node or what ever else I want and I just need to make sure that they listen on different ports. Then, to access any of those projects I just do `something.com:portnumber`.

But I don't really like how that looks. I'd much rather be able to do `something.com/project1` and `something.com/project2`. Is there a way to make one node server listen to port 80, take those names in the URL and then somehow forward the request to the appropriate server?

What's more, it would be great if the URL parameters that got forwarded didn't contain the name of the actual project. To illustrate what I mean take this example:

One node server is runnning and listening on port 1000. It plays songs that you give it in the URL and is accessed like this: `something.com:1000/songname/`

The other node server is listening on port 2000. It does math or something and is used like this: `something.com:2000/add/2/3/`

What I want is to be able to use them like the following:
`something.com/musicplayer/songname/` and `something.com/math/add/2/3/`
preferably without having to change the code of the two servers.

Now, I could do something hacky like redirecting `something.com/musicplayer/songname/` to `something.com:1000/songname/` but I don't want the address bar to show any redirection.

I realize that this seems very specific but I'm pretty sure I'm not the first one that had the idea. I know a lot of people that have their own personal websites where they mess around with stuff but I don't know how exactly something like this is done.

Comment: Can you use a proxy in front of your node server? If yes, then it is possible

Comment: yes, `app.use` can point everything matching a particular path fragment to a separate app. see my answer to a similar question  http://stackoverflow.com/a/17236700/1380669

Comment: I see. That's very nifty.