# URI bind Express.js

Tags: node.js, express

Hello I want to bind the URI of my app, for example lets imagine this scenario.

I am running express app on port 3000,
nginx on port 80, proxying requests of URI `api` to port 3000

And have this route on express

`// Home
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
   res.send('Hello!');
});`

If I try access from **localhost:3000** I get `Hello!` in my browser (that's expected),

but if I try to access from localhost/api I will get an error, of course he can't find the route I'm tryng to access.

If I change app.get to `app.get('/api/...` it works as expected, but this isn't what I want... I would need to prepend `api` in every route, there must be another way to do this, something like:

- URI binding
- URI filter ??

I read the documentation but can't find anything to solve my problem, and I'm thinking of doing a package that does URI bindings on express to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17236700/1380669) for a solution that lets you point every request matching a leading `/api` to a particular express app. In the linked case, the user wanted to do some things without the leading fragment. You could leave out the `app.use(app.router)` for the main express app since you only care about the `/api/` routes.

```
<snip>
var http = require('http');
var express = require('express');
var desktopApp = express();
var mobileApp = require('./mobile.js');

desktopApp.use('/mobile', mobileApp)
desktopApp.use(desktopApp.router);
</snip>
```

Also I am pretty sure that you can actually rewrite `request.url` yourself. I have never tried this so I can't promise it works! see docs http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl Also be sure to put this at the very top of your routing functions, so it is executed before any subsequent routes.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next){
  req.url = req.url.replace(/^\/api/, ''); 
  //the regex replaces leading /api with empty string
  //req.originalUrl will keep the old url
  next();
});
```